# Universal App issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app

Everybody..
I have create one universal application.. 
My app worked fine to only two view.. 
In iphone app worked fine to MainView -> First View -> SecondView -> ThirdView.. 
But in iPad only works to MainView -> First View .. After it can not call to SeconfView..

I have call also this view but not called..

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    languageObj = [[LanguageSelection alloc] initWithNibName:@"Language_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:languageObj animated:NO];
}
else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    languageObj = [[LanguageSelection alloc] initWithNibName:@"LanguageView_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:languageObj animated:NO];
}
```

Nib name also perfect.. View outlet also set in nib file.. But LanguageView not called in iPad only..

Please let me know, is there any wrong thing which i had done..
Thanks..

Comment: your code looks fine. It should work. But can you tell me "Are you using `pushviewcontroller` for MainView to FirstView ? Or `presentViewController` ?"

Comment: pushViewController for MainView to FirstView..

Comment: Do you actually have a `LanguageView_iPad.xib` file in your project?

Comment: yes Dude, if i change only pushView to presentView it works.. But i need pushView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this solved..
I need to add only one line in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method..

```
UINavigationController *navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuView];
```

Thanks for who do their effort to solve my question.. Thanks..

Comment: I did, but it gives warning like "You can not accept your answer in 2 days.."